# In Jenkins - which build step should I add if i'm using protractor?

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I'm new in this kind of subject.
I'm trying to use Jenkins to run my Protractor automation.
My question is - When I create a new job, which build step should I choose? (execute batch command, execute shell, etc)
And what should be happen in the Protractor's side?

If there are any more critic details about the configuration I should know - Please write them.
* I'm using WINDOWS*

Comment: execute batch command (if your protractor has command line support on windows) should do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice between batch or shell depends on you. You can use the one you are more comfortable with. Sounds like it is window, so you can start with batch.

Jenkins will run automatically the workflow that you decided to implement. So you need to know how will your full workflow look like in command-line.

Usually it is something like that:

- pull the sources
- build it
- run the tests (unit-test, integration, regression, etc.)
- send the report

For the protractor, from the official doc, to run the configured tests:

```
protractor conf.js
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/

As it is your first time doing this, just keep in mind that anything that you qre able to do with command-line, you will be able to do it as well with Jenkins.